# iCloud Drive downloads limit hard drive space

Tags: icloud, hard-drive

I have iCloud Drive set up on my Mac and it keeps downloading files in the background. My hard-drive space becomes smaller and smaller and I run into problems with a full hard-drive.

E.g. I was recording a Zoom meeting and it suddenly stopped, because my hard-drive was full due to iCloud-Drive downloads. I now have to remove these downloads every time to free up disk space.

How can I make iCloud stop downloading files in the background?

Comment: Is `optimize Mac storage` turned on in system preferences -> Apple-Id -> iCloud? Also, what Mac model, what macOS version. And what kind of files is it downloading?

Comment: Yes Optimize is on.

Comment: MacBook Air Early 2015 and OS 11.2 (BETA)

Comment: iCloud is a sync system and not a storage system like Dropbox.  It's designed to sync your documents to all devices logged in with the same Apple ID.  If you don't want specific files to sync to your devices, you can change that in your iCloud settings.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that info and since you are running a beta I would expect abnormal/weird behavior sometimes. Usually iCloud Drive will only download files when needed, so something seems to be triggering the download. It is really hard to tell with this limited info.

Comment: How much space is it leaving free? It shouldn't fully fill your SSD but will try to download as much as it can

Answer (score 1):

Right click the file in iCloud Drive, the one you don't need. then, click remove download. this will free up space on your Mac and keep the file in iCloud, where you can download at any time by double clicking it.

Comment: This is no answer since the OP already knows about this and frees up space like that.

Answer (score 0):

Can only click "remove download" after the HUGE download finished. And immediately the next reboot after clicked "remove download", there it goes downloading another 40 GB. This is strangling me and my mere 10GB mobile hotspot quota (of course this happens when you're on the go).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).